# Change from Number to Generated in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, numbers, generated

I am trying to alter a table where the original datatype of this column is Number to a `generated` column, but I get an error of "ORA-00905 Missing Keyword"

```
Alter Table MyTable
Modify Column FlagColumn NUMERIC (38,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE  WHEN ValueColumn IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) VIRTUAL;
```

Is my syntax correct?

Do I have any other options besides dropping and recreating the table?

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle documentation pretty clearly doesn't support the syntax you're attempting. The obvious solution is to drop the *column*, then replace it:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
   DROP COLUMN flagcolumn;

ALTER TABLE mytable
   ADD numeric GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE WHEN valuecolumn IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) VIRTUAL;
```

There's really no reason not to do this, since you're getting rid of the column's original data in any case.